# Dynamically wrapping substrings in quotes

Tags: regex

Say we have an an array of variable size, containing strings `["duck", "goose", "seal", "otter"]`.

We also have a string `redduckalphavolcanobetastringsealgoosegreenblueduck`, the string is then required to be rendered as `red"duck"alphavolcanobeta"seal""goose"greenblue"duck"`.

Largely, I'm not familiar with regex enough to even figure out what to call this operation, so I am sorry if this is a duplicate.

Comment: Since you're looking for a few strings in one long string, I would do a loop of your array and then look for the word in your long string and do a replace.

Comment: which programming language?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution in Perl:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Munge qw(list2re);

my $words = ["duck", "goose", "seal", "otter"];

my $string = "redduckalphavolcanobetastringsealgoosegreenblueduck";

my $regex = list2re @$words;
$string =~ s/($regex)/"$1"/g;
print $string, "\n";
```

Output:

```
red"duck"alphavolcanobetastring"seal""goose"greenblue"duck"
```

The heavy lifting is done by [Data::Munge::list2re](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Munge#list2re-LIST), which converts a list of strings to a regex that matches any of those strings.

The rest is a simple search/replace operation.

[Live demo](https://perlbot.pl/p/6bl1mq).